# How Do I Block Adfree from blocking ads in my apps?

Tags: android, testing, block

Adfree really upsets me as an Android Developer. I release apps in the market for FREE and all I ask is the user views ads while they use my app. I like to make a little money, and not take it from my users pockets. I'm assuming if you found this on Google than I am assuming this bothers you too.
I wrote this little bit of code with a buddy of mine to test if the user has Adfree installed on their phone. If it comes back  positive (the app is installed), it informs the user that they have adfree installed on their phone, and in order to use the app, they must uninstall it. It then proceeds to close the app, so the user cannot use the app until Adfree is gone. 
To begin with, put this in your OnCreate:

```
adfreetest();
```

Now, put this code into your app somewhere (its modular, so it will work in any app)

```
private void adfreetest() {
    try{
         ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager()
                                 .getApplicationInfo("com.bigtincan.android.adfree", 0 );
         //-- application exists
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("To Use this Application, You Must Uninstall Adfree.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        main.this.finish();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
         //-- application doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Make sure to change main in ***main.this.finish();*** to the name of your activity.
If you find a better way to do this, please post!

Comment: Perhaps collect some stats about how many of your users use AdFree? You could be wasting more of your time on those who least deserve it!

Comment: And of course, the age old problem is that you could be setting yourself up as a target here...

Comment: Don't punish the user for disabling ads.

Comment: @jnpcl The author is well within his rights - users viewing ads is how he gets paid. By disabling the ads, the users are using software without paying for it.

Answer (score 2):

The only suggestions I can make are:

- Offer a paid version too, and point the user at that.
- Possibly offer to disable adfree while your app is running. I haven't tried this, but [PackageManager.setApplicationEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setApplicationEnabledSetting%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) might help

Best wishes,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thank you for siding with me on this. Anyways, sorry for posting this as a question, I wanted to put my code up here for any android developer to use. Whenever I google a question, stackoverflow is always a top result so I figured this is where I should share my code.

Comment: By the way, sorry if me posting this code up offends anyone as an adfree user. Just be aware that this code does nothing to your phone. It simply checks your phone to see if you have adfree installed, and if you do, simply alerts you that in order to use the app, you cannot have adfree on your device. No changes are made to your device. Ads are a way of developers getting paid for their work, and if your trying to get away with not letting them get paid, then it is the developers choice not to serve you his/her app.

Comment: Blocking or Uninstalling ad free won't fix the problem as the app doesn't actively block ads, instead it alters the `/etc/hosts/` file to prevent the device from every asking the ad servers for ads.